# Crystal and oscillators for custom ATMEGA328P, is load capacitance needed?

Tags: arduino, oscillator, crystal

I'm designing a barebones Arduino-like board (based on [ATMEGA328P](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/Microchip-Tech-ATMEGA328P-AU_C14877.pdf).) I'm picking the external crystal.

I need to design two board, one "classic board" that runs at 16MHz and a "low power" that runs at 8MHz.

Here are my picks about the oscillators.  I'm not sure if they need external (22pF) capacitors or not.

- 16MHz crystal: [DATASHEET HERE](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/Yangxing-Tech-X322516MLB4SI_C13738.pdf)
- 8MHz crystal: [DATASHEET HERE](https://www.micros.com.pl/mediaserver/Q08.000_5.0x3.2_2_Y_0001.pdf)

Can someone help me figure it out?

Comment: Did you consult the ATMEGA328P datasheet?

Comment: Yes, and i've asked to ee in order to get some help, maybe i've not understood well the datasheet

Comment: If you don't require the accuracy of a crystal, you could consider using a 3-pin ceramic resonator instead. Cheaper, and no (external) capacitors required.

Answer (score 5):

Unless I had a specific reason for diverging from what Atmel/Microchip says, I'd follow the design recommendations in their COMPLETE datasheet (not the one you linked).  They show:

[image: ATMEGA Clock Inputs]

The complete datasheet is here: [ATMEGA328P Datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf)

The image above is from page 26.

Answer (score 3):

From the 16 MHz crystal's datasheet:

[image]

and from the 8 MHz crystal's datasheet:

[image]

That load capacitance needs to be there, without it, the crystal might not behave in a normal way.

It is possible that there is already some loading capacitance inside the microcontroller but this is rare as it is more flexible to have the capacitors off-chip.

As can be seen in jwh20's answer, the datasheet of the ATMega328P states that loading capacitors are needed.

Also I dare you to find a working Arduino like board which uses a crystal and **does not** have any loading capacitors.

So in the end **yes, you need the load capacitors**. Realize that you can always try to not mount them (on the PCB) and see what happens.

But think about this: even many cheap Chinese Arduino boards using a crystal include the load capacitors. If these capacitors could be removed, I am sure these cheap boards would not have them so that a few cents can be saved. But they do (have the capacitors) so you can be assured that they're needed.

Comment: For the OP also the capacitance in the crystal datasheet is usually the total capacitance seen by the crystal, not the value of each single capacitor. 90% of the times you just put two 10pF capacitors and it works but using the right values makes the oscillator more reliable

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the crystals always need capacitors when connected to AVR.

The capacitors may not be 22pF, it might be something else, but since you don't link to specific crystal but a crystal model, as the actual load capacitance requirement of the crystal you will buy is not known, so are the capacitor values.

Comment: Sorry for the missed links, here there are the specific datasheet for the two crystals: 
16Mhz:


8MHz:
https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1809192319_Yangxing-Tech-X50328MSB2GI_C115962.pdf

Comment: @VirtApp there is only one link. And that is a 8 MHz crystal that requires a 20pF load to oscillate at 8MHz. It means that if there is no stray or pin capacitance, it would need two 40pF capacitors, but that is larger than what AVR supports. Max is 22pF capacitors that provide 11pF of load. Adding pin and stray capacitance, it might barely provide almost 20pF of load to the crystal. I think a crystal with smaller CL would better suit for this, but if the frequency is not that important, it will at least simply work with two 22pF capacitors.

Answer (score 1):

You **need** both the capacitors if you want it to reliably oscillate.

They should be close to the **correct** value **for the crystal** and fall within the recommended **range** **for the chip** (12-22pF in this case). If that's not possible, you need to change either the crystal type, the chip type or both.

For example, the 16MHz  YSX321SL for 20pF load is not compatible with the ATmega328, because you would need load capacitors of about 45pF, which is too high. The YSX321SL for 12pF load needs about 20-22pF load capacitance so it is compatible. You could use the 20pF load crystal with 22pF capacitors but the oscillation frequency would be slightly out of spec.

You use capacitors that are approximately C ~= CL*2 - (Cstray+ Cinput). The latter term is usually 3-5pF. That's because they're effectively in series as far as the crystal is concerned. CL is the crystal load capacitance from the crystal datasheet.

Don't worry about getting the last couple pF perfect for most applications.

Comment: So, if i use the YSX321SL i need to use 12pF capacitors, but for the 8MHz X50328MSB2GI?

Comment: No, I said the YSX321SL model designed for a 12pF LOAD needs 20-22pF CAPACITORS as per the formula. The X50328MSB2GI requires higher value capacitors than the MCU recommends, so you should pick a different crystal or a different chip.

Comment: Or use 22pF for the 8MHz and be okay with the frequency being a bit inaccurate because you are only providing about half the 20pF designed load capacitance.

Comment: You could explain this with the respective formula?

Comment: Please re-read what I wrote above and ask if it is not clear.

Comment: So, if i'm not wrong, a crystal with those specs it will be ok: 8MHz ±20ppm 12pF, as (12*2)-5 =~ 19, so, a commercial value can be 22pF and will be inside the specs of the AVR datasheet. are those calculation ok?

Comment: Sounds good to me.